# Log message "_cordovaNative is missing" on Android newer than 3.2

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

On a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0 (Android 4.0.4) and a on Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 4.12), any Cordova application logs the following message, read through command "adb logcat"

> D/CordovaLog(21525): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 966 : Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected for Android 3.2 and lower only.

Does this message indicates that the performance of the app may not be optimal because of the missing "_cordovaNative"?

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.3. To replicate the issue, I connect a device on my computer via USB, and use these commands on a terminal:

```
cordova create test com.example.test "HelloWorld"
cd test
cordova platform add android
cordova run android --device
```

On the other hand, I also tested on a Nexus 5 (Android 4.4.2) and on a Motorola (also 4.4.2) and the "_cordovaNative is missing" warning is not logged.

I do not know if it is related to the issue, but the `cordova build` command outputs:

```
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
```